# Serial Communication Using C

Tags: c, serial-port, uart

I'm trying to read the on board temp sensor of the `msp430fr5739` micro controller and display the results in a terminal.

using `C` the task should be accomplished!!!

All the code and custom libraries can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microcomputers/Self-Study/tree/master/Ex2)

My operating system is ubuntu and the IDE I'm using is [code composer studio](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/tools-software/ccs.page)

here is the main.c

```
#include <msp430fr5739.h>
#include "system.h"
#include "temp.h"
#include "uart.h"
/*
    main.c
    1. Switches and LEDs
    2.
    3. Temp sens
 */ 

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer

    unsigned int tempVal = 0;   // temp readings

    LEDs_INIT();                // Init leds
    SWITCHEs_INIT();            // Init Switches    
    serialBegin();              // Begin Serial communication at 9600 buad

    while (1)
    {
        __bis_SR_register(LPM4_bits + GIE); // Enter LPM4 with interrupts enabled
        tempVal = getThermisterVal();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to follow the  [demo](https://github.com/Microcomputers/CodeComposerStudio)  code that  [TI](http://www.ti.com/)  had shipped with the board and the resulting libs are published on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microcomputers/Self-Study/tree/master/Ex2) (I didn't post all the lib and code, simply because it's too long)

Now I'm really struggling with the serial communication part, i know that the bytes sent from the micro-controller has to be read by some sort of serial monitor application on PC.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use libserialport (https://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport). I made a cmake-compatible version if you'd prefer to use that: (https://github.com/ScottMudge/libserialport-cmake).

Comment: @Scott, some example code would have been nice :)

Comment: Well I mean it really depends on the application. Libserialport is relatively simple to use (extensive doxygen documentation here: http://sigrok.org/api/libserialport/unstable/index.html), but you'll have to parse the data coming out of your MCU, depending on how it is being serialized.

Comment: Yes, that's right! I was just trying to `make` the llib from your fork and it gives uncountable fails e.g. `CMakeFiles/serialport-shared.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/serialport-shared.dir/serialport.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/serialport-shared.dir/serialport.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/serialport-shared.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/serialport-shared.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed`

Comment: Are you using MinGW? If you're using Unix/OSX, I would use the standard libserialport repo. If you need windows libs, let me know and I can compile them for you.

Comment: I've tried the standard libserialport and there are errors in build process :(